# How to query automatonymous sagas instances to check if other instances have the same value?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, masstransit

Lets assume I have an order state machine and instance, I also have the repository to save the info to my postgres database.

An update event arrives to update the delivery date in my order, but I want to check that no other instance of the other orders have the same delivery date before updating (because I only have 1 delivery man).

The solution I have so far is just creating a custom Activity, but want to know if this is the correct approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework Core, you can add your `DbContext` (which includes the saga class map) as a dependency on your activity and query the table to see if there is another matching date and handle the outcome appropriately. The entire operation will be in a transaction, as MassTransit starts a transaction before loading the saga instance.

Comment: Awesome! Thats what I thought. Another quick question, do you recommend having a DbContext per StateMachine or is it ok to use the single Db context approach?. Btw love your youtube series :)

Comment: If those saga instances are stored in the same database, I'd likely put them in the same DbContext.